# Issue with for loop in C

Tags: c

I was creating an `int` array and making all of its element `0` in `C`.

Using:

```
int arr[50],i;
for(i=0;i<50;i++){
    arr[i]=0;
}
```

Which works fine if used inside a function or in `main()` like:

```
int main(){
    int arr[50],i;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++){
        arr[i]=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But something strange happens if we use the code outside of any function like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int arr[50],i;
for(i=0;i<50;i++){
    arr[i]=0;
}
int main()
{
     printf("Hello World!");
     return 0;
}
```

Gives error on compilation:

```
error: expected identifier or '(' before 'for'    
 for(i=0;i<50;i++){                                           
 ^
```

So by that, is it that grammar of `C` doesn't support looping outside of a function?

If no, then why is this happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're defining an *anonymous* block, which is not allowed (it needs to be predeceded by a function definition, otherwise, the compiler will never know when it will have to execute it).

In C, every line of code but variable declaration/initialization must lie within a function.

The only things that may appear at the top level of a translation unit are declarations or function definitions.

Comment: Thanks for spending you time answering question. +1.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is confusion in **programming paradigm**. If I'm not mistaken (I may be! Just a guess...) you are familiar with python programming, which is written in an imperative paradigm. This means that within a file each line is read and performed top down, one by one. In such a paradigm your proposed *code outside of a function* would operate just fine.

Since you are writing in the C language you are writing in a **procedural paradigm** (or definitive paradigm). This means that code blocks are to be defined in procedures (functions) and can be referenced procedure to procedure. Calling one procedure launches the program, in C programming this one procedure is the main() procedure, recognized by name. Any code written outside of a procedure is syntactically incorrect (some exceptions I believe, macros and the like...).

Since correct syntax is the first requirement of program compilation in C (and all other procedural programming languages) the error occurs when attempting to compile and run this code.

I do hope this helps with a greater understanding! Paradigms are fun, they are the *rules* of using a certain language.

Comment: Thanks for spending you time answering question. +1, Btw I'm not familiar with `python` but I code in `js` in which such code runs fine.

Comment: One of the paradigms of javascript is imperative, I guessed wrong! haha. Take a look at the paradigm table here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_multi-paradigm_programming_languages

Answer (score 1):

For executing a loop in C, it has to be inside a function. Otherwise compiler will not have any idea when to execute this piece of code. Most of the C compilers will give a compiler error in this case. Only variable initialisations/declarations can appear outside of a function

```
#include <stdio.h>
int arr[50],i;
/* This piece will not get executed
    for(i=0;i<50;i++){
      arr[i]=0;
    }
*/
int main()
{
     printf("Hello World!");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spending you time answering question. +1.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with looping in particular. All the statements must be put inside functions, otherwise... tell me, when do you think the code outside a function must be run? Have no idea? And the compiler too

Comment: Im assuming OP thinks it would run top to bottom, before main() is run.

Comment: That Makes sense, Thanks for spending you time answering question. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize an array to 0 by just defining it with the first element initialized to zero.

```
int arr[50]={0};
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, and spending you time answering question. +1.